# Adding a button to the title bar Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, imagebutton

Haven't been able to find quite the right answer for this yet. I want to add a button into the navigation / title bar at the top of a Xamarin Forms Navigation Page. Note that I need to know a method that will work on android, I'm not interested in trying to find an iOS only solution here. This button needs to be an image button as I want a way to access a hamburger menu.

Comment: Could you please add some more detail about what you've tried already and any code snippets you've used?

Comment: none of the code snippets I've tried have worked in the slightest, so I really have nothing to show.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use `ToolbarItem` from  `YourPage.xaml.cs`:

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Search", "search.png",() =>
{
  //logic code goes here
}));
```

In Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
    <ToolbarItem Icon="search.png" Text="Search" Clicked="Search_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

**Update**

Xamarin.Forms introduced `TitleView` in 3.2.0 that you can customize title of the navigation.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestPage">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Button ... />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: How it will look like in xaml?

Comment: @tytyryty:     <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="search.png" Text="Search" Clicked="Search_Clicked"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

Comment: @Kowalski - I feel like a superb answer. But could u plz tell me, from where the `"Search_Clicked"` event catch ?

Comment: at YourPage.xaml.cs `private void Search_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args){}`

Comment: Can we add AbsoluteLayout instead an icon in the toolbar, so that we can manage more than one thing as an icon? Like, add to cart icon with the badge.

Comment: @RohitSharma You can now use [`TitleView`](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-title-view-a-powerful-navigation-view) for more complicated title bars